# Error compiling a Groovy project using @Grab annotation

Tags: gradle, groovy, groovy-grape

I'm compiling a Groovy project with Gradle, but I've noticed that when I use the @Grab annotation in my code, I get the following error:

```
$ gradle compile
:buildInfo
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
```

(full stack trace here http://pastebin.com/0ty4jNct)

I've found out that the only way to get it working is to add the 'groovy' and 'ivy' module to the *groovy* classpath, but I would like to avoid this, since the *groovy* classpath is deprecated.

Is this a Gradle bug? or there's a better way to manage the @Grab dependency?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`@Grab` is meant to be used for standalone scripts that aren't precompiled, and you wouldn't normally use it together with compiled code. If you do, you may have to add Ivy to `groovyClasspath`. Something like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    ivy
}

dependencies {
    ivy "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.5"
}  

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyClasspath += configurations.ivy
}
```

That said, a better approach is to manage dependencies with Gradle.

Comment: Hi, I think you mean: `configurations { ivy }` and use it in the `dependencies` block, but it returns `Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: configuration ':compile'`

Comment: Right. And of course you'll have to declare a Groovy dependency.

Comment: Is it possible to have a Groovy "script" that can be ran both standalone (with `@Grab`) as well as in Maven context?

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution worked for me at compile-time, but I still had similar issues at runtime.  The following worked for me by excluding the grape code from the compile altogether:

```
compileGroovy {
  groovyOptions.configurationScript = file("gradle/config.groovy")
}
```

... where `gradle/config.groovy` is a separate file, contents of which were:

```
withConfig(configuration) {
  configuration.setDisabledGlobalASTTransformations(['groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation'] as Set)
}
```

Comment: It looks like Gradle 7.4 added an option for disabling AST transformations without the file - [`compileGroovy.disabledGlobalASTTransformations`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompileOptions:disabledGlobalASTTransformations). The default value is `["groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation"]` which would then be disabled. So, if you use `@Grab` in your code, you would then add a compile dependency for it to work in Gradle then at runtime it would "grab" the dependency, so you get both to work.